# What are int8, int64 and string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, types

At the interview, they were given the task to make tables with int8, int64 and string types but in PostgreSQL no such types. What are int8, int64 and string in PostgreSQL?

I fount that int64 may be BIGSERIAL or BIGINT and String is Varchar

Comment: [If only there was documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)...

Comment: Copy/pasting the post title into Google provides a wealth of info.

Comment: I think even Chatgpt might get this one.

Comment: I didn't find any information in the link that explicitly said at least about int64.

Comment: OK, with the help of Google, I found out that int64 is bigint, but what is int8?

Comment: Int64 and Int8 are the same (both Bigint). They both specify the *size* of the integer field. Int64 specifying  a 64bit integer and Int8 specifying an 8byte integer (8bytes * 8bits/byte = 64bits).  Beyond that string is also `text` data type (at least in Postgres)

Comment: You didn't find anything about int64 [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) because there is no such thing in Postgres (there is int4 however).

Answer (score 0):

They were trying to fool you by showing you data types that don't exist, with the exception of `int8`, which is the internal name for the standard `bigint` type). You would use `text` for strings. `int64` doesn't exist in PostgreSQL.